# Is it safe to install Ubuntu 16.04 beside WIndows 10 with UEFI?

Tags: windows, uefi

So I am kinda worried about installing Ubuntu on my main PC, since I love it.

But the problem is, my motherboard is UEFI. Its a gigabyte h81m-hd3.

Would it be safe to dual boot Windows and Linux on this? Also, is the installation as easy as installing it on a PC that has BIOS? (I have Ubuntu on my laptop)

Also, last question, let's say I installed Ubuntu and Windows, and Windows gets an update, can the update break the Grub2 bootloader?

Thanks for your help, if I am able to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my custom build PC I'd be happy as hell.

Comment: Perhaps you should take a backup first? That way, if something doesn't work, you can revert to the backup.

Comment: I agree with Jo. Backups are *always* a good idea no matter how many or which operating systems are on your computer. Even though Ubuntu doesn't interfere with other operating systems by itself it's very easy for beginners to make mistakes during the installation or accidentally tell Ubuntu to do something that breaks Windows. There are so many questions on AskUbuntu from people who clicked “Erase everything and install Ubuntu” instead of “Install Ubuntu and keep Windows”.

Answer (score 2):

Normally it *should* work. Ubuntu is capable of getting installed in UEFI mode and along with Win 10, but you might face (normally solvable) problems depending how well the UEFI is implemented and how closely integrated the Windows boot loader is.

I, for example, had to set UEFI to load the Windows boot manager (could not make it to load GRUB) and configure that one again using Windows' `bcdedit` command to directly load GRUB instead of booting Windows. Then in GRUB I can decide which OS to boot.

However, once it is set up, it works flawlessly.

Until the next major Windows update (not the monthly stuff, maybe once a year or so) that resets and overwrites the boot loaders again to boot only Windows. You should be prepared to reinstall GRUB and reconfigure the Win bootloader again, which takes only about 5 minutes if you know what you're doing though.

So it's definitely worth trying to set up an UEFI dual-boot of Win 10 and Ubuntu, but the installation might be a bit trickier depending on your UEFI system implementation. Just back up your data and try it out, once you get stuck with a specific problem, we're here to help you out.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Byte Commander's answer; however, it's also worth noting that most modern UEFIs provide a Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which enables them to boot BIOS-mode OSes. Since you refer to a Gigabyte motherboard, not a computer from a vendor that sells whole systems (like Dell or Lenovo), it's likely that you installed Windows yourself, and it could be installed in either BIOS/CSM/legacy or EFI/UEFI mode. You can determine the boot mode in Windows 10 by using the `msinfo` tool, as described [here.](http://www.nextofwindows.com/windows-8-quick-tip-how-to-tell-if-my-windows-is-uefi-booted)

When you install Ubuntu, the OS will install in whichever mode was used to boot the installation medium, which might or might not match what Windows uses. It's easier to match if Windows is installed in EFI mode, because you can usually disable the CSM to guarantee an EFI-mode boot. (See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) for more on this subject.) If you boot the Ubuntu installer in its "try before installing" mode, you can open a Terminal window and type `ls /sys/firmware/efi`. If you see files, you've booted in EFI mode; but if you get a `no such file or directory` error message, you've booted in BIOS mode. If you're in the wrong boot mode, you should try again. My page on the CSM provides some tips for how to manage your boot mode.

Comment: My Windows is installed through UEFI,  so if I install Ubuntu through UEFI, it will be all good?

Comment: You definitely should use the same boot mode for both OSes. That's just one hurdle, though; any number of other things can go wrong, resulting in anything from trivial annoyances to complete loss of your existing Windows installation. I strongly recommend backing up everything, or at least your important personal data, before proceeding; and proceed with caution -- don't barrel ahead if you don't understand something or see something unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Ubuntu quiet a few times and never experience any problem with Windows and Ubuntu.  Initially when UEFI first took off with popularity with manufacturers there were special steps needed to ensure they worked together.  But since 16.04 I have found dual booting Ubuntu and Windows to be very seamless.

There are two things that I have to check when installing Ubuntu for dual boot.   (1) On some machines I find it necessary to turn off Secure boot.  (2)  I have to ensure to boot UEFI when booting the Live install session.

Ubuntu recognizes an UEFI boot and will advise the user that it will be installing in that mode.  It'll give the option to check.  I have noticed that when I choose that option, it won't give the option again in that session.  It'll just install Legacy.

So, as long as I boot UEFI it'll install UEFI by default.  Once the install is complete it will install the Grub boot manager which will present boot OS's in the boot menu.  I have the choice to boot to either.

I never use Windows Boot manager.  In fact for many of my clients, when I operate on their computers, I install Ubuntu on a small partition so that I can have access to maintenance tools if they have a problem with Windows.

Grub becomes the default boot manager.  I set it to boot Windows by default.  I'm usually the only one to use Ubuntu on their computer.  Either will boot seamlessly just using the Grub boot manager.

One of my main computers is a UEFI Gigabyte motherboard, I installed Windows 10 on it in order to give support and test troubleshooting for giving assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small update, I managed to get everything to work. It was a pain in the ass at the beginning, but later on i managed to get it working with all the drivers required.